# How to remove and override CSS attribute from parent class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a file bootstrap.min.css which has the following class

```
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

I created a new css nav-tabs.css which has

```
.nav-tabs {
    font-size:18px!important;
}
```

How do I remove the font-size from parent if the requirements change in the future?

Comment: What do you mean by `parent` *from parent if the requirements change*

Comment: You don't need !important. If your new CSS for .nav-tabs is after the bootstrap default, the new one will override the default.

Comment: @enguerrans I did't want any dependency on the order

Comment: @Mr.Alien bootstrap.min.css is the parent css/class

Comment: So just be more specific with your selector. 'body .nav-tabs' will override your default style in a clean way. (Btw, it's not a parent, it's just the same selector)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `!important` unless you really, really have to.

You can change the font size in this case by either adding the new css after the old like so:

```
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size:14px; /*old*/
}
.nav-tabs {
    font-size:18px; /*new*/
}
```

Likewise using two style sheets the same will apply:

```
<link href="/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> //old
<link href="/Your_Custom_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet"> //new
```

or probably preferably by being a little more specific in the selector like so:

```
.nav-tabs { /*less specific*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size:14px; 
}
.nav-tabs li { /*more specific, li is just an example*/
    font-size:18px; 
}
```

Comment: what if I want to delete an attribute from bootstrap.min.css class?

Comment: At least, body .nav-tabs should allways work, as he should have a body in all cases :)

Comment: @redmave If you're hosting your own css files there's nothing stopping you from just going in and editing the file when you need to make changes, just be sure to add comments to the file so the next dev knows it has been changed.

Comment: @redmave you can reset a property with the default/initial value. You can find some here: http://nimbupani.com/safe-css-defaults.html

Comment: @apaul34208 I would prefer leaving the bootstrap file alone so any later upgrades will not break the UI. So, you are saying that it is not possible to delete an attribute from the css file placed at the beginning of the file by later ones?

Comment: @redmave I'm saying the opposite, if you have two selectors with equal specificity, the later will take precedence. See [tzi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21027054/1947286) for a more complete explanation

Comment: Sorry typo. I meant the reverse. I wanted order independence.

Comment: @redmave then use a more specific selector

Answer (score 4):

The `!important` declaration is not mandatory.

There is other ways to override a CSS rule.

**1. Selector specificity**

The browsers calculate a specificity for every selector with a group of 3 different counters. Each counter is infinitely greater than the next one:

1. IDs;
2. Classes, pseudo-classes & attributes;
3. Elements & pseudo-elements.

Some examples of selectors increasingly specific:

```
a { }                     /* 0,0,1 is lower than */
.button { }               /* 0,1,0 is lower than */
input[type="submit"] {}   /* 0,1,1 is lower than */
#header {}                /* 1,0,0 is lower than */
#header a {}              /* 1,0,1 is lower than */
#header a:hover {}        /* 1,1,1 is lower than */
#header a:hover::after {} /* 1,1,2 */
```

If a selector has a lower specificity than another one, its rules will be overrided.

In your case, the two rules have the same specificity.

**2. Order**

If two rules have the same specificity, the one loaded last win.
It could be in the same file, the one at the bottom win, or in two different files, the file at the bottom of the HTML file win.

So if you want to override the bootstrap rules, you have to make that your rules have the same weight and that your stylesheet is loaded after the one of bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nav-tab.min.css">
```

I hope the explanations will be useful.

Cheers,
Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `!important` which is a dirty way to do so, use a more specific selector like

```
div.class_name .nav-tabs { /* More specific selector */
   /* Styles */
}
```

The above selector will target `.nav-tabs` nested inside a `div` having `class` `class_name`, so this makes it unique, as well as it will override the properties in `.nav-tabs` *(Yes, you need to re declare the properties again, else if yo don't, other properties will be picked from `.nav-tabs`)*

Comment: i agree, but fyi - there doesn't have to be a space between the unit and the !important (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you have 2 css files either edit the bootstrap one to your liking or have the one that you want to override the other above the other one in the `<head>` like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav-tabs.css"/>
```

Comment: I just saw your profile, you should take a while and read the FAQ section to understand how this website works :) if you keep posting such answers, they will be downvoted and eventually you will be **Answer Banned**

Comment: !important can never be the right way ;) Or maybe, only for some hacks.